# Pandas: Collapse a mxn multi-index dataframe into a series by repeating each row index n times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a two dimensional dataframe in Pandas with two levels of indexing. For a sample, it looks like this:

```
Location    1   2   3   4   5
Time 
  0         2   4   6   8   10
  1         1   3   5   7    9
  2         0   0   0   0    0
```

I want to collapse this into a single-indexed dataframe where the main index repeats for each column index, which would look like this:

```
Time    Location    Value
  0         1         2
  0         2         4
  0         3         6
  0         4         8
  0         5        10
 ... so on.
```

How can I achieve this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need `stack`

```
df.stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: `df.stack().reset_index(name='Value')`

Comment: @HighVoltage yw : -) happy coding